# Override virtual function in grandchild class

Tags: c++

I am working on a compiler and I am trying to build the data structure for storing expressions (AST).

Can I override the virtual function like below in the Grandchild class and not in the parent?

It only makes sense to evaluate it in the lowest class Add_expr. I'm also assuming since I set evaluate() = to 0 it is required in all children classes or else I will get a linker error if not implemented.

```
struct Expr {
    virtual void evaluate() const = 0;
}

struct Binary_expr : public Expr {

}


struct Add_expr : public Binary_expr {
    virtual void evaluate() const override {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not likely that you will get a linker error for pure virtual function which is not overridden (with a special exception of pure virtual destructor). Instead, you will have a compiler error, but only if you try to instantiate the class which has pure virtual functions which still have not been overridden.

Which means, that in your question, it will all work correctly unless you try to instantiate objects of type `Binary_expr`.

Comment: Can I call the constructor for binary_expr when constructing a add expr?

Comment: If I remove = 0 could I instatiate a binary then?

Comment: @nfgallimore not sure what you mean by  'removing = 0'. You can certainly have a constructor defined for `binary_expr`, and than you can 'call' this constructor from the derived class constructor.

Comment: I’m just trying to avoid writing 4-5 specialized functions for every kind of binary expression. I can generalize each as operand operator operand e.g., print or cout overloader

Comment: I will update the question when I can, driving sorry

Comment: @nfgallimore you can't have it both ways. Either `binary_expr` can be an object on it's own, and than it has to provide the function, or it can not, than it doesn't have to provide the function, but than you can't create an object of this type.